# Get Subset of MultiIndex Pandas DataFrame with Single Index Boolean Indexer

Tags: python, pandas

If I have this dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
tuples_index = [(1,1990), (2,1999), (2,2002), (3,1992), (3,1994), (3,1996)]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples_index, names=['id', 'FirstYear'])
df = pd.DataFrame([2007, 2006, 2006, 2000, 2000, 2000], index=index, columns=['LastYear'] )

df
Out[2]: 
              LastYear
id FirstYear          
1  1990           2007
2  1999           2006
   2002           2006
3  1992           2000
   1994           2000
   1996           2000
```

And i'd like to get a subset of the dataframe where the groups based on id are longer than one, I could do this, but its slow:

```
%timeit df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.36 ms per loop
```

My df has tens of millions of rows and a huge number of groups as well (most groups are of len 1) so the time adds up.  I can get a boolean indexer much more quickly this way:

```
%timeit df.groupby(level=0).size() > 1
1000 loops, best of 3: 364 µs per loop
```

But the boolean indexer only has the id as its index:

```
id
1    False
2     True
3     True
```

I guess maybe I gave more context than necessary, but how can I use a boolean indexer with a single index to get a subset from a dataframe with a MultiIndex?  Desired output would be:

```
              LastYear
id FirstYear          
2  1999           2006
   2002           2006
3  1992           2000
   1994           2000
   1996           2000
```

Comment: Any operation that requires *copying* data from the original DataFrame into a new DataFrame tends to be slow when the DataFrame is large. `df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)` is slow because it returns a new DataFrame with data copied from arbitrary locations within the original DataFrame. `df.groupby(level=0).size() > 1` is relatively fast because it is generating a smaller DataFrame -- less data copying required. Using the boolean indexer to generate the filtered DataFrame will not save time, because *that step* will require copying.

Comment: I didn't realize that was how it worked, thanks! What's the proper way to close the question considering there isn't really a solution?

Comment: I didn't post the statement above as an answer because I can't prove that it is true. Perhaps leave the question open, just in case I am wrong. The comment above will either stand the test of time or challenge someone to show there is a faster way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` and `transform` to build a mask

```
df[df.groupby(level=0).transform(np.size).gt(1).values]
```

[image]